# Tomcat server not running in eclipse with project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat7

I have one basic web project using spring in eclispe.
I have installed tomcat v7 .

Now when i start server alone , without adding any application then it runs ok
but when i add the project to server and then strat it then error comes

```
"Tomcat 7 failed to start"
```

Initially the project was working properly but then i deleted few spring jars and then i added again but i get this error.

Now is there any way to find whats the problem. Any log files???

Comment: I've seen this many a time, it's not a great error message but usually it's do do with the classpath. Check that you have all the required tomcat/catalina jars on the classpath.

Comment: where can i find that which jars are missing and how can i add those jars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend not starting it in Eclipse until you can start it outside of Eclipse successfully.

Open a command shell, make sure that the Tomcat /bin is in your PATH, and execute the catalina.bat script.  You'll be able to see more detailed messages, if any, in the shell.

You should also check the Tomcat /logs directory to see what they can tell you.

The CLASSPATH ought to be set properly in the startup script.

UPDATE:

Since you know you can start Tomcat without Eclipse, you know that the issue is in the IDE.

My guess is that your project needs the Tomcat /lib JARs to be available and they're not.  You can probably tell Eclipse to add all the JARs it finds in a particular directory to your CLASSPATH when you build and run (you can with IntelliJ).  Right click on the project root and see if there's a drop down to add to the path.

Comment: outside the tomcat is working properly , i can see the webpage on http://localhost:8088/  , even the server starts ok in eclipse without my project but when i add the project then the problem comes